# How can I list installed masked packages in Gentoo?

Tags: linux, package-managers, gentoo

Every now and then when updating my Gentoo Linux system, I get the message `The following installed packages are masked`.  These are typically packages that are no longer developped and that I would like to remove.  However, I am also in the middle of my system updates, and by the time I'm done, I have forgotten which packages they were.  How can I get `emerge` to show me the list of installed, masked packages (and nothing else)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`# emerge -av eix`

then:

`$ eix-update`

`$ eix --installed-masked`

From `man eix`:

```
   --installed-unstable, --installed-testing, --installed-masked
          Only match packages which have at least one non-stable,  testing,
          or   masked   version   installed   (the  test  acts  as  if  LO‐
          CAL_PORTAGE_CONFIG=false).  If several of these options are  com‐
          bined in one test, it is the same version which must satisfy all
```

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK you cannot trigger it alone - this functionality is defined as function called in different actions by emerge.

Definition is in `site-packages/_emerge/depgraph.py` file in proper python directory for your portage implementation.

There is poor man's option to use `eix`. First `eix-update` and then `eix-test-obsolete b | grep '^\[?\]' | awk '{print $2;}'` which unfortunately lists also packages from overlays.

You can also use previously mentioned file `depgraph.py` but it cannot be used easily outside `emerge` file from `/usr/bin/emerge` and requires some python knowledge.